# Printing Bar-code Crystal Report in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, crystal-reports

I am working on a project that prints bar-code labels using crystal reports in windows forms application by c#.

the problem is what happens when i am trying to print the report:

at the end of every page there are two free labels added to the printed report.
i want the report to be printed continuously without any gabs or free labels in between pages.

here is the report page setup and the printer preferences:

[image: Page setup & Printer preferences] 
[image: the result of printing]

as the picture shows, my report has 4 bar-codes, and every page in the report has only 2 bar-codes, so i have 2 pages to be printed ... after every page there are the 2 free labels as the picture,

the question is how to prevent that and print the 4 bar-codes without any gabs?

Comment: I would double/triple check printer settings, and print some labels from other sources out with the same settings to ensure they are correct. Label size, top/bottom margin and advance/reverse could potentially cause that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the crystal report headers and footers.

Open your report and suppress all its headers and footers if you are not using them. (Suppress report header, report footer, page header and page footer)

Hope you have set your printer settings properly.

[image]

Comment: the height value of all of them is  = 0 and this is the a picture  of the report at design time  ![Report at design](http://s32.postimg.org/m5zwofjwl/report.png).

Comment: The picture is showing 1+ pages which means it has two pages. Please suppress the header and footer. It solved my issue. I have put a screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Yes there are 2 pages as I mentioned before, the problem is that the 2 pages turns into 4 pages as there are 1 free page added after every page and I don't know where they come from 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]:  https://i.imgsafe.org/21a8aac.png

Comment: I suppresses All headers and footers , but unfortunately the same result, nothing changes, but when I tried to change the hieght of report page to be 30 cm as it can hold all barcodes in 1 page , there are 1 page at the report page at runtime and as expected 1 page at the offline printer , no more free pages added, but something strange happens when I connected the printer it just prints only the first 4 barcodes

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]][1] [![enter image description here][2]][2] [1]:https://i.imgsafe.org/8167a78.jpg [2]:https://i.imgsafe.org/b22e664.png

Comment: See what happens when I am trying to use offline printer it suppose to be just only 2 pages like the report but at the printer it's 4 [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]:https://i.imgsafe.org/8d68e1e.png

Answer (score 0):

[solved]

i keep watching the number of pages at the report and offline printer
i found that the number of pages always get duplicated at the printer how ever i changed the height of the report page for example to be 1 cm there always one free page at the end of every page,

[image: offline printer]

so i tried to change the width of the Details Size to be more width and make all margins equal 0

[image: details size]

then it get worked fine as expected

[image: test result]